# NHibernate many-to-many and SELECT N+1 problem

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-many

I have 4 database tables (Channel, User, Message, User2Channel) and according entity classes:

```
class **Channel** { 
 int ChannelId {get;set;}
 int ISet<User> UsersToChannel {get;set;}
 ...
}
class **Message** {
 int MessageId {get;set;}
 Channel Channel {get;set;}
 User User {get;set;}
 ...
}
class **User**{
 int UserId {get;set;}
 ISet<Channel> Channels  {get;set;} 
 ...
}
```

I use fluentnhibernate for mapping:

```
class **ChannelMap** {
    ChannelMap(){
       ...
       HasManyToMany(x => x.UsersInChannel)
                .AsSet()
                .Cascade.All().Inverse()
                .Table("User2Channel")
                .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
}
class **UserMap** {
    UserMap(){
       HasManyToMany(x => x.Channels)
                .AsSet()
                .Cascade.All()
                .Table("User2Channel")
                .Not.LazyLoad(); 
    }
}
```

I load messages in this code:

```
...
var query = session.CreateQuery(@"select m from Message m"); 
var msgs = query.List<Message>();
...
```

At profiler I see many queries like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM User2Channel WHERE ChannelId=654
SELECT ... FROM User2Channel WHERE ChannelId=655 
etc
```

Please! Help me! How I can solve this problem? If I have many thousands Channels - I get also many queries into database!

Answer (score 2):

You could load them using batches. This is the less intrusive option (means: you don't need to do anything in your domain code).

I don't know fluent. So this is the xml mapping you need:

```
<set name="Channels" ... batch-size="50">
  ...
</set>
```

This lets NH prefetch 50 channels at once. It will query them like this:

```
SELECT ... FROM User2Channel WHERE ChannelId IN (654, 655, 656, ... 704)
```

This makes the `N+1` a `N/50+1`.

Comment: Stefan is right. Also, the multiple queries when executing the query are caused by the `Not.LazyLoad` that you added.

Comment: Thanks for this comment Diego. Had a linq query that featured a Fetch statement and also had Not.LazyLoad specified in the Mapping - this caused 2 queries to be called. Removed the Not.LazyLoad in the mapping and all is great.